# Naming PCs on a mixed hosts home network

Tags: networking, dns, ics

I have a home network comprising an Apple iMacs and a Windows 7 PCs - using the internet connection sharing feature on the Windows 7 PC to share the internet connection with the iMac.

I have configured the hostnames on each pc so, running hostname on the Windows 7 box says "windows7" and on the iMac says "apple", but, if I try and "ping apple" from Windows 7 or "ping Windows7" from the iMac they can't resolve.

what do I need to do to get this 'simple' level on connectivity working?

Comment: Have you tried pinging the IPs as well?

Comment: pinging the ip's works. But because ICS dishes up the ip's using DHCP they change. Well, the Windows 7 ICS host is always 192.168.0.1 so I can hardcode that.

Comment: Do you have any AV software running? I believe this was once a problem with Trend Micro

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to have resolved itself. Mostly it seems to have been a case of problem-exists-between-keyboard-and-chair.

At any rate - ICS seems to have invented a 'mshome.net' workgroup, and appended that to the generated hostnames. So, I CAN successfully ping - from both the mac and windows pc, 'imac.mshome.net' and 'win7.mshome.net'.

I guess, all I have to do now is add 'mshome.net' to the list of suffixes in the DNS settings on both computers. Strange that thats not automatic.